# When merge to NSManagedObjectContext changes in existing objects, data in NSFetchedResultsController does not update

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

We have:

- 2 threads;
- Each thread has its `NSManagedObjectContext`;
- Each thread has its `NSFetchedResultsController`;
- The delegates of `NSFetchedResultsControllers` not null;
- In the main thread `NSFetchedResultsController` is used to work with tables;
- In the secondary thread `NSFetchedResultsController` is used only for data access.

If you have added new objects, then changes are merged with the contents of the second thread `NSManagedObjectContext`.

If the objects were added, then `NSFetchedResultsController` updates the data in accordance with the request.
If the properties of existing objects were modified, then `NSFetchedResultsController` not update the data.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Is your update code path separate from your insert code path? If so, have you verified that your update code path is saving changes on the context?

Comment: The merge function calls in my thread when properties of objets are changed, so objects are saved in other thread.
`
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onChangeDBC:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
...
-(void)onChangeDBC:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateMOC:) onThread:myThread withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
}
....
-(void)updateMOC:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [cdHelper.mOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The mostly likely cause is that you did not implement the FRC delegate method:

```
– controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:
```

... properly. Specifically you need to check for a change type of `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` and then update the table row cell for that particular object with the changed value.

Comment: I implement empty function
`-controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`

Comment: That is your problem. An empty method will not work. Delegate methods have to be populated to perform their task. In this case, the delegate method is supposed to update the table for changes identified by the controller.

Comment: No, that is not problem because my method works for inserted objects and does not works for updated objects. NSFetchedResultsController in main thread updates data when i add and i update objects.

Comment: The `controller:didChangeObject...` method is not called at all for updated objects? Or it is called but the tableview does not update? If your not sure, log the `forChangeType:` value to see what it is responding to.